# Creating a User Initiated Send definition in SSJS

Tags: javascript, marketing-cloud, api

I am trying to create a User Initiated Send definition in my Business Unit with the following code according to the wiki example: http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/send_server_side_javascript_functions/

I am receiving an error message: "Error adding EmailSendDefinition."

```
    var esdParams = {
        "CustomerKey" : "Test",
        "Name" : "Test",
        "EmailSubject" : "Test"
    };
    Send.Definition.Add(esdParams,"Default Transactional","TestEmail",89136);
```

"TestEmail" = the name of my email (not sure how to retrieve the external key?)

"89136" = the ID of my list

Does anyone have any ideas or some working examples I can try?

Answer (score 1):

```
var emailProperties = Email.Retrieve({Property:"Name",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"NAME_OF_EMAIL"});

var emailKey = emailProperties[0].CustomerKey;
```

Just replace "NAME_OF_EMAIL" with the name of your email -

Answer (score 0):

The value "TestEmail" is the Name of the email, however that parameter is expecting the Customer Key value.  In order to get the Customer Key value for an email, a retrieve will need to be done where you filter on Name.

Example syntax for doing an SSJS retrieve on email can be found at:
http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/email_server_side_javascript_functions/

Comment: Doesnt work in 2023